# Use MetdataId to find the Attribute Name of a deleted attribute

Tags: metadata, dynamics-crm

When I query the metadata using `RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest`, the `RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse` returns `EntityMetadata` and `DeletedMetadata`.  The `DeletedMetadata` only returns the `MetadataId`.

Is there a way to get the metadata for the attribute without knowing the entity?  Even just the attribute name would be fine.

`RetrieveAttributeRequest` I think only works if the attribute exists and if you have the `entitylogicalname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only infomration available is the MetadataId.

Quoting from the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrievemetadatachangesresponse.deletedmetadata.aspx):

> This collection is a dictionary of GUID values using a
>   DeletedMetadataFilters as a key. The GUID values represent MetadataId
>   values of the metadata items.

Looking at another part of the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863599.aspx#BKMK_RetrieveInformationaboutDeletedMetadata) specifically addresses this question:

> You will also use DeletedMetadataFilters enumeration as a key to the
>   RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse.DeletedMetadata to filter the GUID
>   values found in the RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse.DeletedMetadata
>   property. When you design a metadata cache you will want to use the
>   MetadataId for each item so that you can identify deleted metadata
>   items and remove them.

So as a developer you are expected to populate a cache of metadata of interest to your application. You can query the CRM Metadata to find changes and deletes - but in the case of a delete you are responsible for having collected the metadata in your cache.